# Shared pointer to an array of shared pointers

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I defined an array of shared pointers called table as follows; now I want to make this table a shared pointer as well. however I am not sure how to do that. I appropriate help with that.

```
class Reference {
public:
  int ref;
    Reference (int r)
  {
    ref = r;
  }
   ~Reference ()
  {
    cout << "destructor " << endl;
  }
};

class segment
{
public:
  std::shared_ptr < Reference > *table;
  segment ()
  {
    table = new std::shared_ptr < Reference >[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      {
        table[i] = std::make_shared < Reference > (i);
      }
  }

};
```

Comment: What is SIZE? Why don't you declare the table as a vector of shared pointers?

Comment: Thanks! I tried vector<shared_ptr <Reference> > table. but that does not make table a shared pointer right? it only contains shared pointers...

Comment: sorry, vector would not work, you want to use a std::array or a c array?

Comment: I used c++ array in my example, why that will not work? can you please explain why std::array will be better? tnx

Comment: Your question should be much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd say that

#### You probably don't need shared pointers in class `segment` at all.

Your `table` field is an area of fixed size (`SIZE`). If you're worried about its lifetime - just think about the lifetime of instances of `segment`. You can instantiate *segments* with a shared pointer, i.e. `my_segment = std::make_shared<segment>()`, and then pass that around even after going out of scope

Now, as for the multiple shared pointers being the contents of `table`: You are creating them altogether and will likely get rid of them altogether when you destroy the `segment`. Unless you're thinking of `segment` as a sort of an "hors d'oeuvre" plate from which others will copy different shared pointers, then you throw the plate away; that's not the case, is it? Assuming it isn't, just have a `Reference table[SIZE]` member, and be done with it.

Notes:

- Your code actually has table be a raw pointer to shared-ptrs, which is probably not what you meant, since that's not what make_shared gives you.
- You didn't say much about what the `Reference` type is about. That may have impact on this answer too; I'm ignoring its suggestive name.